# Problem Solving with Straight Line Graphs?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, problem-solving

***THE QUESTION:***

$A$ is the point $(-1,5)$. Let $(x,y)$ be any point on the line $y = 3x$.

**a)** Write an equation in terms of $x$ for the distance between $(x,y)$ and $A(-1,5)$.

**b)** Find the coordinates of the two points, $B$ and $C$ on the line $y = 3x$ which are a distance of root $74$ from $(-1,5)$.

I drew a diagram but that didn't really help me.

For part a) I tried to form an equation using pythagoras's theorem but I got a really obscure quadratic equation.

For part b) I am thinking that the root $74$ is the hypothenuse, then I tried to break down root $74$ but couldn't find any square numbers that would fit into it (only root $37$ and root $2$).

I might be thinking on the wrong lines so any help would be appreciated!

(Just for extra info, I started A-Level Maths in September).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint: use the Distance formula**

Write distance between $A$ and point $P(x,y)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$, then, replace $y$ with $x$ using the relation for $x$ and $y$ ($y=3x$).

Now, once you've got this relation, equate it to $\sqrt{74}$ and solve for $x$. Again relate $x=y/3$ to get $y$.

This way, you'll get two $x$ values, and two corresponding values of $y$, giving you two points $B$ and $C$.

The distance is: $$\sqrt{(-1-x)^2+(5-y)^2}=\sqrt{(-1-x)^2+(5-3x)^2}$$

Now, equating and solving:

$$\sqrt{(-1-x)^2+(5-3x)^2}=\sqrt{74}$$
implies
$$10x^2 -28x -48=0$$
which has solutions:

$$x=4,-6/5$$
Corresponding $y$ are:

$$y=12,-18/5$$

Comment: But how do you find the distance between $A$ and $P$?

Comment: @HankaLangerova Haven;t you been taught this formula (the one in purple box near the end)? http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm

Comment: Oh wait. Got part a) Thanks!

Comment: but when you say equate to it root 74, do you mean I should make the equation I got from part a) equal to root 74?

Comment: I got the answers (-4,-12) and (6/5, 3.6) what do you think?

Comment: @HankaLangerova (sorry for the late reply, timezone differences) I've included a solution in my post, please have a look.

Comment: @HankaLangerova You only flipped the signs of the values, otherwise they're correct, good job! :) If my answer has helped you please consider accepting it. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!